# How to put Java correctly inside the Perl?

Tags: function, perl, expression

The Javascript alone works fine with the 'True' result. But when I tried to insert it into the Perl language, it didn't work. Probably it doesn't read regular expression correctly? I'm still new to both language.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

print "<script type='text/javascript'>
    var reZip = /^\d{5}$/

var num = '12345';

    if(reZip.test(num))
    {
    alert('True');
    }
    else
    {
    alert('False');
    }

</script>";
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? why do you want java inside perl? based on what you have you are just printing the java script. You want to use CGI

Answer (score 2):

`$/` is the record-separator variable in Perl (`"\n"` by default). Inside the `""` string, it is being substituted in

```
var reZip = /^\d{5}$/
```

Also, because this is a `""` string, the `\d` is being interpreted as an unknown escape and subtituted with just `d`.

[Heredocs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3c_EOF_) are better for multiline strings, and you can use the single-quote variation to prevent interpolation.

```
print <<'END';
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var reZip = /^\d{5}$/

var num = '12345';

    if(reZip.test(num))
    {
    alert('True');
    }
    else
    {
    alert('False');
    }

</script>
END
```

Comment: Thanks, your answer fulfilled my question.